# Relationship between kernel and support

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces.
Let

$f:V \to W$

We know that the **support** is

$\operatorname{supp}(f) = \{ v \in V  \mid  f(v) \neq 0 \} $

and that the **kernel** is

$\ker(f)=\{ v \in V \mid f(v)=0 \} $

Is there a relationship between the two? It seems to be that if we combine the kernel and the support we have the whole of V, because the evaluation f(v) is either 0 or not 0. I haven't seem a connection between these two in my course's lecture notes so I have the feeling I am completely misunderstanding this topic.

Comment: You are correct. Using your definitions, the vector space $V$ is the disjoint union of $\ker(f)$ and $\operatorname{supp}(f)$. Note that if $f$ is linear, then $\ker(f)$ is a subspace while $\operatorname{supp}(f) = V \setminus \ker(f)$ is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no any other fancy relation than they form a partition of $V$.

In linear algebra, the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of a linear transformation is not an interesting object since it is not even a vector space. However on the other hand, in functional analysis, one would see a lot this concept due to a useful technique called [mollification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier).